# visualvm - Local java applications cannot be detected

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

I am trying to run visualvm in my Windows 8 machine and i am getting error 'Local java applications cannot be detected'. I tried to follow the below steps to resolve the issue as suggested in 'https://visualvm.github.io/troubleshooting.html'. I gave full permission to my 'AppData\Local\Temp\hsperfdata_Dhasan' folder. But still i am getting the same error whenever i start visualvm. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Quit all java applications and delete `hsperfdata_Dhasan` folder.

Comment: I deleted hsperfdata_Dhasan folder and restarted my machine. But still getting the same error. Also, i dont have admin rights in my system. Will it be a problem?

Comment: This is strange. Can you check that hsperfdata_Dhasan folder was created in AppData\Local\Temp\ after you deleted it and started VisualVM again?

Comment: I should add that "Dhasan" will be your computer username.

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer. It worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. One point is important to mention here, the link in the error dialog goes to a page with an explanation like this: The created folder is lower-case, if your user name has uppercase letters, delete the folder and make a case sensitive one, BUT, in my case, the "exact opposite" was the case. The existing folder had uppercase letters of my UserName, I deleted it, didn't create anything and just ran jvisualvm again, and all was fine. So, just delete the folder.

Comment: This worked for me:

1. Stop all Java applications (ALL, including any IDE and VisualVM itself)
2. Delete the folder: C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\hsperfdata_XYZ
3. Run VisualVM again.
4. Now, run any IDE and/or the Java application to be monitored.
5. The process will appear under the "Local" section in VisualVM.

Thanks @TomasHurka

Answer (score 0):

I am using *Visual VM 2.1.7* and what worked for me is to delete the 'hsperfdata' file and run the `visualvm.exe` from `bin` folder.
Note that I don't have admin access, so I couldn't give the full permission as well, but nevertheless this worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).